# jquery file returning errors in netbeans

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, netbeans

I've downloaded the lastest jquery file from the jquery website and I've installed the file into my php project. I'm currently using Netbeans IDE 8.0 and jquery-2.1.1.min.js

When I open the jquery file to view its contents it returns numerous errors.

Main Errors:

> expected semicolon; after ")" 
>   expected "===" and instead saw "=="
>   expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment
>   expected semicolon; after "b"
>   expected semicolon; after "c"

Netbeans or JQuery issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you edit your question with your written code ?

Comment: I didn't write the code. The jquery-2.1.1.min.js file was downloaded from [link](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/05/01/jquery-1-11-1-and-2-1-1-released/) and placed into my php project. When I open the jquery-2.1.1.min.js file it displays errors. I've listed the errors above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just linting errors. The script will work fine, but Netbeans is just recommending you make those changes to make it more readable, which you don't need as it is a minified file. Basically don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for that Nat. Appreciated!